# Regular expression matching with re but not lex

Tags: python, lex, python-re

I am trying to parse a file in order to reformat it. For this, I need to be able to distinguish between full line comments and end of line comments. I have been able to get lex to recognize full line comments properly, but am having issues with end of line comments.

For example: "*a = 0; //This; works; fine*" but "*a = 0; //This, does; not;*".

What confuses me the most is that re is able to recognise both comments without issue and yet lex can not.

Here is the relevant code (FL=full line, EL=end of line):

```
tokens = (
    'EQUAL',
    'SEMICOLON',
    'FL_COMMENT',
    'EL_COMMENT',
    'STRING'
)
t_EQUAL = r'='
t_SEMICOLON = r';'
def t_FL_COMMENT(t):
    r"""(^|\n)\s*(//|\#).*"""
    return t
def t_EL_COMMENT(t):
    r"""(?<=;)\s*(//|\#).*"""
    return t
def t_STRING(t):
    r"""(".*")|([a-zA-Z0-9\</][\w.\-\+/]*)"""
    return t
def t_newline(t):
    r"""\n"""
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
t_ignore = ' \t'
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s' on line %d" % (t.value[0], t.lineno))
    t.lexer.skip(1)
def t_eof(t):
    return None

lexer = lex.lex()

lexer.input(file_contents)

for token in lexer:
    print(token)
```

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to be a [mre] - anyone should be able to copy/paste your code and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem. You need to include imports and some _minimal_ data.

Comment: Really, you should have submitted an [mre]. Please do this next time; it will be much easier for anyone trying to help you, and perhaps even better for you. I know that SO rules can seem a bit over-demanding and maybe even arbitrary, but there is a good reason for them: they save time, and when you rely on volunteers to provide answers, their time is precious. And here's the thing: please don't take this the wrong way; it's a simple observation: you don't really understand the technology you're using or the problem you are having. Otherwise we wouldn't be here. So you shouldn't assume you...

Comment: ... actually know what's relevant to the problem. If you just include everything, or better still strip everything down to a simple example *which shows the same symptom*, then you don't have to worry about that. And we don't have to rely on your necessarily imperfect description of what you think is relevant. In short: never describe anything which you could show. (Use text, not images. In this case, a picture is *not* worth a thousand words.) And never include any code which cannot just be run without modification. Because someone will want to do that to be able to help you.

Comment: In this case, I think I know what's wrong, but I can't really test it because I don't have a complete program from you. I don't know what I can't see. I just have to guess and I could be way out to lunch. My answer would be a lot better if it included real, tested code, and I would be happier with it had I been able to do that.

Comment: I have already updated the posting to include a minimal example.

Comment: @Eric: if it were a minimal example, I could copy and paste it into a file named `example.py` and then type `python3 example.py`, and see the problem you have. I cannot do that, because it is not a complete example. Minimal does not mean incomplete. It means get rid of stuff which isn't necessary to show the problem.

Comment: Also, once I fix that code up so that it imports ply and defines the parser input (using command line arguments is usually helpful for that, by the way), your example which says "this works fine" does not actually work fine. It recognises the comment as several ordinary tokens, not a comment token. And your claim that "re is able to recognise both comments without issue" doesn't show the actual call to some re module function (although I can guess that it was search rather than match, which is what Ply uses).

Comment: Anyway, just take it as a suggestion for future questions, OK? It really does make life easier for everyone. Even for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lex (including the Ply variety) builds lexical analysers, not regular expression searchers. Unlike a regular expression library, which generally attempts to scan the entire input to find a pattern, lex tries to decide what pattern matches at the current input point. It then advances the input to the point immediately following, and tries to find the matching pattern at that point. And so on. *Every character in the text is contained in some matched token.* (Although some tokens might be discarded.)

You can actually take advantage of this fact to simplify your regular expressions. In this case, for example, since you can count on `t_FL_COMMENT` to match a comment which does occur at the beginning of a line, any other comment must be not at the start of a line. So no lookbehind is needed:

```
def t_FL_COMMENT(t):
    r"""(^|\n)\s*(//|\#).*"""
    return t

def t_EL_COMMENT(t):
    r"""(//|\#).*"""
    return t
```

An alternative to `(\n|^)` is `(?m)^` (which enables multiline mode so that the `^` can match right after a newline, as well as matching at the beginning of the string).